# git_clone() clone just .git folder (libgit2)

Tags: c++, git, libgit2

when I perform git_clone() , it runs successfully, but it clones just .git folder. When I use

git clone http:/url.adress.com/myRemoteRepo C:/destination/to/clone

in terminal, it clones also another folders, not just .git folder and I want git_clone() to work that way, is that possible?

### My code:

```
  int num=0;

git_libgit2_init();

git_repository *cloned_repo = NULL;

int error = git_clone(&cloned_repo, all_urls.at(num).c_str(), clone_to.at(num).c_str(), &clone_opts); 

if (error != 0) {

    const git_error *err = giterr_last();

    cerr << "error in clone num " << num << " -> message :" << err->message << endl;

}

else cout << endl << "Clone " << num << " succesful" << "(from url : " << all_urls.at(num) << "    " << "to path : " << clone_to.at(num) << ")" << endl;

git_repository_free(cloned_repo);

git_libgit2_shutdown();
```

---

There is how I set options

```
git_clone_options clone_opts = GIT_CLONE_OPTIONS_INIT;
        // git_checkout_options checkout_opts = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT;
        // clone_opts.checkout_opts = checkout_opts;
        clone_opts.fetch_opts.callbacks.credentials = cred_acquire_cb;
```

After commenting these 2 lines, it is working

Comment: `clone` operations usually are followed by an automatic `checkout`. That's why there is a `checkout_options` defined inside `clone_opts`, but you do not specify how you initialize those...

Comment: @rodrigo I added code to set options

Comment: after commenting checkou_opts initialization, its working

Comment: I'm guessing that the default clone config instructs to checkout HEAD, while the default checkout config does not have any branch set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it works after commenting out the checkout options is that `git_checkout_options` defaults to dry run for the checkout strategy. `GIT_CLONE_OPTIONS_INIT`, on the other hand, initializes the checkout strategy to `GIT_CHECKOUT_SAFE`. You can get the same behavior by setting the strategy on your checkout options:

```
clone_opts.checkout_opts.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_SAFE;
```